# How to get a sub string from string using word starts with some text

Tags: java

I am trying to read the word from a string using some starting text. For example

String str = " Ads : 234983  ABCD2987423 availabe"

In the above example, the value will change every time. So I want to read the string which starts with the text "ABCD".   i.e (ABCD2987423)

Note: Sometimes the extra text will be added in the string, So index won't work in this example.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `String#replaceAll` for a one-liner using regex:

```
String str = " Ads : 234983 ABCD2987423 available";
String text = str.replaceAll(".*\\b(ABCD\\w*)\\b.*", "$1");
System.out.println(text);
```

This prints:

```
ABCD2987423
```

Comment: Thank you Tim. Giving following error message for the expression  -  Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )

Comment: @daithashankar Maybe reload your page.  The code I have in my answer does work (I tested it).

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution. Using streams but no regexes.

Split the string into an array of words, then pick the first word that starts with ABCD.

```
String[] words = " Ads : 234983 ABCD2987423 available".split(" ");
String foundWord = Stream.of(words).filter(w -> w.startsWith("ABCD")).findFirst().get();
```

Note: If no word in the input starts with "ABCD", the optional produced by `findFirst` throws `NoSuchElementException` when calling `get()`.

Comment: Why not replace `.findFirst().get()` with `.findFirst().orElse(null)` to avoid exception?

Comment: It's an alternative. Depends on what should happen if that string is not found. Is that an error? Then handle it in an exception. Or is `null` expected return value in that case?

Answer (score 0):

In case you plan to use this frequently, you could use `RegExp`:

```
public final class AbcdExtractor implements Function<String, String> {

    private final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<abcd>ABCD\\d+)");

    public String apply(String str) {
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
        return matcher.find() ? matcher.group("abcd") : null;
    }

}
```

Then you code could look like this:

```
AbcdExtractor extractor = new AbcdExtractor();
System.out.println(extractor.apply("Ads : 234983 ABCD2987423 availabe"));                       //  ABCD2987423
System.out.println(extractor.apply("This is another string with ABCD2987423 and with suffix")); //  ABCD2987423
System.out.println(extractor.apply("This is string without data"));                             //  null
```

[Demo: https://regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/lbxh69/1)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read the string which starts with the text "ABCD" and what precedes it is a whitespace char or it can be at the start of the string and what follows can only be a whitespace char or the end of the string, you could use [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
(?<!\S)ABCD\w*(?!\S)
```

- `(?<!\S)` Negative lookbehind, assert what is directly on the left is not a non whitespace char
- `ABCD` Match literally
- `\w*` Match 0+ times a word char
- `(?!\S)` Negative lookahead, assert what is directly on the right is not a non whitesspace char

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aM6i43/1) | [Java demo](http://ideone.com/S1JI8S)

For example

```
String regex = "(?<!\\S)ABCD\\w*(?!\\S)";
String string = "Ads : 234983 ABCD2987423 availabe\n"
     + "Ads : 234983 #ABCD2987423 availabe\n"
     + "Ads : 234983 ABCD2987423# availabe\n"
     + "Ads : 234983 #ABCD2987423# availabe";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
}
```

Output will only match the first

```
ABCD2987423
```